# Change application gamma/contrast/brightness or substitute a colour

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, gdi+

How can I change the contrast/brightness of a winform app - not the entire display, just my application? I was thinking it might be possible to do this using GDI+ but I've not a lot of experience with this and I can't find any code examples.

Everything that I've looked at either changes the entire display or is designed for controlling these attributes in images.

Alternatively is there a way that I can substitute a colour? For example any time the colour white is used in the app it should be substituted for grey.

I toyed with the idea of placing a semi-transparent panel over the window but can't find how I would pass mouse clicks through this when it's above all other controls.

Comment: See: http://bobpowell.net/RGBHSB.aspx

Comment: @BrianSnow: that link has absolutely nothing to do with the question.

Comment: @GJKH: The simple answer is no.  You can not adjust a single window's gamma (or color substitution) without either custom drawing the entire window, contents, and child windows.  I suppose one could also rewrite the window manager.. but that's even more ridiculous.

Comment: You can just change the color not the brightness, however you may still have to create your own controls (including forms)... That's not a trivial task.